# Dual Messenger - Where are files stored (e.g., WhatsApp)

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, file-system, samsung-dual-messenger

I had a working WhatsApp (say, WhatsApp W1 in phone PC) in my Samsung J7 Prime, Android 7, recovered with the usual *Backup to/Restore from Google Drive*, from phone A (PA).

I meant to install a [Dual Messenger](https://www.sammobile.com/2017/07/25/dual-messenger-on-galaxy-j-2017-devices-lets-you-use-two-accounts-in-social-networking-apps/) - WhatsApp, restoring for it a copy (W2) from another phone (PB).
So I would have

> W1 PA -> W1 PC 
> W2 PB -> W2 PC

[This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-note-8/help/dual-messenger-whatsapp-question-t3698812) is the only reference I found on how to do it (which is a workaround, as if no "official" way of doing it existed).
Since some people acknowledged in comments that it worked, I followed it. I skipped the part of recovering Media from W2 PB.

Now I have the two working WhatsApp accounts, that is fine, so far.
But I am left with the following file structure:

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/.Shared            <- From W1 PC
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/.trash             <- From W1 PC
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Backups            <- From W1 PC
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Databases          <- Copied from W2 PB
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Databases_PhoneA   <- Renamed from W1 PC
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media              <- From W1 PC
```

I have questions:

1. Where are files (messages, media, backups, etc.) for each WA installation stored?
2. Will I end up with a "broken" WA structure, which will cause problems? (so far everything is working fine).
3. Is `/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Databases_PhoneA` needed?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung's Dual Messenger/Dual App data is stored on

- `/Internal Storage/DualApp/WhatsApp`
- `/storage/emulated/0/DualApp/WhatsApp`

*For Samsung S10e, S10, S10+, Fold, Note9, S9, S9+, Note8, S8, S8+, S7, S7 edge, A80, A70, A50, A30.

Comment: That is not where my files are stored on my S10e. I have no clue where they are but it's not under either of those directories.